Test interaction with Laravel queue events
I have a package with multiple event listeners that listen to the events emitted by the Laravel queue:
class SetTrackableJobProcessingStatus
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct(
        public TrackableJobUpdater $updater,
    ) {}

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(JobProcessing $event): void
    {
        $jobUuid = $event->job->uuid();

        if ($this->updater->trackableJobModelExists($jobUuid)) {
            $trackableJobModel = $this->updater->retrieveTrackableJobModel($jobUuid);

            $this->updater->setProcessingStatus($trackableJobModel);
        }
    }
}

Which uses these methods in the TrackableJobUpdater service class:
class TrackableJobUpdater
{
    /**
     * Set the job status to processing and update the started_at timestamp.
     */
    public function setProcessingStatus(TrackableJob $trackableJob): bool
    {
        return $trackableJob->update([
            'status' => Status::Processing,
            'started_at' => now(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if a trackable job model exists for a job using its uuid.
     */
    public function trackableJobModelExists(string $uuid): bool
    {
        return TrackableJob::where('job_uuid', $uuid)->exists();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a trackable job model using a job uuid.
     */
    public function retrieveTrackableJobModel(string $uuid): TrackableJob
    {
        return TrackableJob::where('job_uuid', $uuid)->sole();
    }
}

How would I go about writing a test case for this, I can test that the listener works (passes):
class SetTrackableJobQueuedStatusTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_listens_to_laravel_job_queued_event(): void
    {
        Event::fake();

        Event::assertListening(JobQueued::class, SetTrackableJobQueuedStatus::class);
    }
}

I want to also test that the the listener works when a job starts processing. How can I manually dispatch/start a JobProcessing event in the exact same way Laravel dispatches it? I tried:
public function test_updates_processing_status()
{
    $jobProcessingEventListener = new SetTrackableJobProcessingStatus(new TrackableJobUpdater());
    $jobProcessingEventListener->handle(new JobProcessing('default', new TrackedSuccessfulJob()));
}

Where TrackedSuccessfulJob is a normal job class that extends a custom tracking class.
But this gives me the warning:

Expected parameter of type '\Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job' expected

And the error:

Call to undefined method uuid() on 

Simply dispatching a job like: TrackedSuccessfulJob::dispatch(); does not dispatch all events. For example, the JobQueued event is not dispatched.
